# How to remove empty fields on Update

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When I remove an array element from a document field, I would like to remove that field, if zero length, or empty object. I do not want fields with empty arrays or empty objects saved on db.

I use this snippet for update document:

```
        await documentInstance.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id,async(error,doc)=>{
          await empInstance.findByIdAndUpdate(employId,{
            $pull:{
                documents:req.params.id
            }
          },{omitUndefined:true});    
        });
```

When I remove the only item from array, I get an empty array.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you'll be after the `$unset` operator.

Comment: Could you show me how to do it?